# PowerBi - R Plotly No Plot Produced

Tags: r, powerbi

I'm working to create a visual in Power BI using R plotly library (which I see is now supported by Power BI) but I am receiving an error which states "No image was created. The R code didn't result in creation of any visuals. Make sure your R script results in a plot to the R default device."

Here is the code:

```
g <- plot_geo(dataset, lat = ~Latitude, lon = ~Longitude, color= ~Dollars)
g_info <- g %>% add_trace(hoverinfo = "text", hovertext = paste("DMA: ", dataset$DMA_NAME, "Dollars: ", dataset$Dollars))
g_info
```

In RStudio this works great and results in the interactive map which I am trying to produce. However nothing will show up in Power BI.

Seems like every article about this is from 2017 before plotly was supported so I'm hoping there is something simple that I'm missing with today's PBI environment.

Answer (score 1):

They should pull plotly off the list of supported R libraries for Power BI. It's not properly ready yet.

Comment: Completely agree!  So many finicky steps to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little bit more complicated to use R plotly within PowerBI than just R ggplot as it renders an html and not a just a graphic like png. Here is how to do it:
https://towardsdatascience.com/interactive-power-bi-custom-visuals-with-r-a6a4ac998710

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to integrate R into Power BI. Go to "get data" in Power BI and on the list of all sources, choose R. Then you need to enter the directory of the R program files on your machine in order to link the two together.

Comment: Can you provide some screenshots / code snippets?